# how to fix this bug while i am creating new shopify app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

when i run dev this message appear :
"Error: Could not start Cloudflare tunnel: Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with
quic: timeout: no recent network activity"

```
Could not start Cloudflare tunnel: Failed to create new quic connection error="failed to dial to edge with quic:
timeout: no recent network activity"
2023-11-11T07:01:55Z INF Retrying connection in up to 4s"
```

i tried nothing *_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately cloudflare is facing a lot of issues, i recommend using ngrok

Steps ->

1. Install ngrok (if you have not)
2. Run ngrok : ngrok http {app port}
3. Start dev server : npm run dev -- --tunnel-url {ngrok url}:{app port}